# Tally Values using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can we tally data values which are in different web pages using selenium web driver?
    What are the codes ?
    Those data are in same website but two web pages.
    I want To Tally Total sale using Invoice And Return Sale

Comment: are these values present on the same website or different

Comment: Same website. but different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `driver.navigate()` to hit the first desire URL and then save the value in a string variable, now again navigate to the 2nd required page and save the value. Now compare it

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved");
String country =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"arpa-table\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]")).getText();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.iana.org/numbers");
String country2 =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"rir-map\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")).getText();
if(country.equalsIgnoreCase(country2))
{
    System.out.println("Country are similer");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("country are not similer");
}
```

I have used simple if else to validate the similarities.

But you can use Assert of TestNG or Junit to validate it

```
Assert.assertEquals(country, country1);
```

refer the below URL for more info :-

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/assertions-in-testng

Hope it will help you :)